# Is it true that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}-\frac{b-a}{g(b)-g(a)}=f'(c)-\frac{1}{g'(c)}$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions on the closed interval $[a,b]$, and differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$, where $a<b$. If $g'(x)\neq 0$ on $(a,b)$, then does there exists $c$ on $(a,b)$ such that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}-\frac{b-a}{g(b)-g(a)}=f'(c)-\frac{1}{g'(c)}$?

Note that $g(b)-g(a)\neq 0$ by Rolle's theorem.

By Lagrange's mean value theorem, there exist $c$ and $d$ on $(a,b)$, such that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}-\frac{b-a}{g(b)-g(a)}=f'(c)-\frac{1}{g'(d)}$. I guess that $c$ and $d$ can have the same value.

Comment: In general the $c$ and $d$ you will find will be different, so this is not usually true.

Comment: @OsamaGhani It's not enough to disprove it since there may exists $e\neq c,d$ satisfying the equation. An example is Cauchy's mean value theorem, that is $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$. But if we use Lagrange's mean value theorem twice, then $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(d)}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a composite function $f\circ g(x)$ Hence we have $$
 (f\circ g)'(x)= f
 '(g(x)) g'(x) $$

> That is, when $f\circ g(x)=x$, then $\frac{1}{g'(x)} =f'(g(x))$

In general we guess that $f'(g(x)) \neq f'(x)$

Consider $f(x)=x^2,\ g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$, which is a counterexample : $\frac{f(0)-f(1)}{0-1} = \frac{g(0)-g(1)}{0-1}=1$

Further, $f'(x)=2x,\ g'(x)= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ so that $2x-2\sqrt{x}\neq 0$ for all $x\in (0,1)$

Answer (score 2):

Consider two functions $f$, $g$ such that $f'(x)=1/g'(x)$. Then the RHS is always zero, but not necessarily the LHS.

Example: Let $g(x):=x^3$, $f'(x)=\frac{1}{3x^2}$, so $f(x)=-\frac{1}{3x}$. Take $a=1$, $b=2$, to get $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}-\frac{b-a}{g(b)-g(a)}=\frac{1}{42}\ne0=f'(c)-\frac{1}{g'(c)}$$ for any $c\in[1,2]$.